# Math Induction proof union and intersections

Tags: induction

I'm totally new to Math Induction. I have a question on using Math Induction proof with union and intersections.

Here's the initial problem:
Prove that, for if C, D1, D2, …, Dn are n + 1 sets, that

$$C\bigcap(\bigcup_{i=1}^nD_i)=\bigcup_{i=1}^n(C \bigcap D_i)$$

**Basis step.**

Prove P(1).

$$P(1):C \bigcap D_i = C \bigcap D_i$$

**Induction step**

Write out P(k) by replacing “n” with “k” in the original equation.

$$P(k): C\bigcap(\bigcup_{i=1}^kD_i)=\bigcup_{i=1}^k(C \bigcap D_i)$$

**Proof**

Using the assumption that P(k) is true, add k+1 on the left-hand side and replace “k” with “k+1” to the right-hand side.

$$P(k+1): C\bigcap(\bigcup_{i=1}^{k+1}D_i)=C \bigcap((\bigcup_{i=1}^kD_i)\bigcup D_{k+1})$$

RHS (associative properties - change the grouping )

$$=C \bigcap(\bigcup_{i=1}^kD_i)\bigcup D_{k+1})$$

Question: are we just replacing the k with k+1?  if so why? or am I totally off?

RHS of P(k+1)

$$=C \bigcap(\bigcup_{i=1}^{k+1}D_i)$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to prove that:
$$ C \cap \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} D_i \right) = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} (C \cap D_i) $$

The first step is to prove that it holds for some value of $n$. It is obvious that the equality is verified for $n=1$, so we can proceed. We assume that the equality holds for some $n$, and we prove that this implies that the equation holds for $n+1$. Pay attention to this step: we are proving that, if the equality holds for $n$, then it also holds for $n+1$. Since we know that $n=1$ is true, this will lead us to conclude that $n=2$ holds. But then, $n=3$ holds, and so on. This is how proof by induction works. So we suppose that the equality is verified for some $n$, and we want to prove that this implies:
$$ C \cap \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1} D_i \right) = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1} (C \cap D_i) $$
Note that the LHS can be rewritten as:
$$ C \cap \left(\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} D_i \right)\cup D_{n+1}\right) $$
By the distributive law, $A \cap (B \cup C) = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$. Thus, we obtain:
$$ C \cap \left(\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} D_i \right) \cup D_{n+1}\right) = \left(C \cap \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} D_i \right)\right)  \cup (C \cap D_{n+1})  $$
But, using the inductive assumption, this is the same as:
$$ \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} (C \cap D_i) \right) \, \cup \, (C \cap D_{n+1})  $$
which is equal to
$$ \bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1} (C \cap D_i)  $$
as we wanted to prove. Thus, the proof by induction is complete.